# Arch Linux + MongoDB - GLIBCXX_3.4.22 not found

Tags: arch-linux, mongodb

I have [mongodb installed](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MongoDB#Installing_MongoDB) on my Arch linux:

```
$ sudo pacman -S mongodb
$ pacman -Qi mongodb

Name            : mongodb
Version         : 3.2.6-2
Description     : A high-performance, open source, schema-free document-oriented database
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : http://www.mongodb.org
Licenses        : AGPL3
Groups          : None
Provides        : None
Depends On      : pcre  snappy  openssl  libsasl  boost-libs  yaml-cpp  wiredtiger
Optional Deps   : libpcap: needed for mongosniff [installed]
                  mongodb-tools: mongoimport, mongodump, mongotop, etc
Required By     : None
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 102.28 MiB
Packager        : Bartlomiej Piotrowski <bpiotrowski@archlinux.org>
Build Date      : Fri 13 May 2016 09:40:18 AM BST
Install Date    : Thu 30 Jun 2016 05:24:15 AM BST
Install Reason  : Explicitly installed
Install Script  : Yes
Validated By    : Signature

$ mongo
```

But I have this error below:

> mongo: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found
>   (required by mongo)

I have searched around and install:

```
$ sudo pacman -S libstdc++5
```

But I still have the same problem when I try to start mongo.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

**EDIT:**

```
$ pacman -Qs gcc-libs
local/gcc-libs 5.3.0-4 (base)
    Runtime libraries shipped by GCC
```

And:

```
$ pacman -Qo /lib/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 is owned by gcc-libs 5.3.0-4
```

Comment: `libstdc++.so.6` is in `gcc-libs` from the `base` group (or, alternatively, `gcc-libs-multilib`). Do you have thoose?

Comment: @Wieland I don't think I have `gcc-libs-multilib`. Pls see my edit above. I only have `local/gcc-libs 5.3.0-4 (base)`

Comment: Ah, so you've done a partial upgrade at some point. [Don't do that](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported), it's not supported.

Comment: @Wieland what should i do then? what is `a partial upgrade`?

Comment: What a partial upgrade is and what you should do are explained in the link from my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by upgrading all packages in my server:

```
$ sudo pacman -Syu
```

Not ideal but a quick fix.

Comment: With Arch being rolling release, it'd always a good idea to only do `-S package` and `-Syu`, never `-Sy package` or `-Sy`, since any single package downloaded may not be compatible with the rest of the system otherwise.